# How can I sync keys/licenses between several WMDRM license servers?

Tags: licensing, registry, drm

I'm setting up a system with WMDRM and would like to have two servers for redundancy. I will put a load balancer in front of them and have them both handle requests.

I cannot figure out how/where the issues licenses are stored on the license server.

It's pretty easy to give the servers the same signing key (it's in HKLM/Software/Windows/WM Rights Manager

Maybe there even is no need to sync keys between the servers - as long as they encrypt content using the same key, they can both issues licenses for the content with a client requests a license?

So, my questions are:
- Is something stored on the license server for each content item?
- Can I access that stored thing and transfer to another server?
- Is it needed at all?

Sorry for the vague questions - but that is a one-to-one reflection of the documentation :)

Thank you!

Comment: Try asking this on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the content seed on the same machine and the same code to generate a license, then you should be all set.  There is no other data that is required to be replicated.

There is a license server private key I believe stored in the registry (installed when you enroll the license server on http://licenseserver.windowsmedia.com) but there is no reason why these need to be in sync.